# How should I use these tags, [multithreading] and [concurrency]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The description for [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) is

> Multi-threading is the ability of a computer or a program to perform work concurrently or asynchronously by utilizing multiple concurrent streams of execution (generally referred to as threads).

For [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concurrency) it's

> In computer science, concurrency is a property of systems in which multiple computations can be performed in overlapping time periods. The computations may be executing on multiple cores in the same chip, preemptively time-shared threads on the same processor, or executed on physically separated processors.

I don't see consistent usage of those tags by the community/askers. Sometimes it's just one of them, sometimes both and I think it's because the words intersect in their meaning a lot. Therefore, I'd like to make sure I've understood the difference myself:

IMO:

- Use [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) when it's a technical, specific to a framework or tool, question.
- Use [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concurrency) if it's a theoretical, about visibility, synchronization, tasks, question.

Would you say I'm on the right track with those definitions?

Comment: I know this is nominally about tags, why was my comment saying that this is still a SO question not a meta.SO question deleted?

Comment: @philipxy Why is it better on the main site in your opinion? I think it would be hardly on-topic there as it is about terminology, not an actual programming problem. Further it addresses the inconsistent usage of the corresponding tags, which is inherently a meta topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the Wiki suggests, concurrency is a property or an ability of something, e.g. an algorithm or a system. An algorithm can be designed in a way in which it processes data or tasks concurrently. A system like a server can be designed in a way in which it handles requests concurrently.

Multi-threading is everything that is related to making a concurrent algorithm or system run parallel, i.e. actually running on different threads. So this is where we start talking about visibility, synchronization, frameworks and tools.

With this in mind we can say that questions should be marked by [concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concurrency) when the question is about the design of a concurrent algorithm or system. Some examples:

- How to split an algorithm into concurrent tasks?
- How to design a system that handles problems concurrently?
- ...

Mark a question by [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) when it's about anything that is related to making a concurrent algorithm or system run parallel. Some examples:

- How do I make writes made by one thread visible to other threads?
- How do I synchronize threads to assure correctness of a program?
- How to organize the usage of threads to actually increase performance?
- How to use this specific tool of that specific framework?
- What is the right tool or right data-structure to solve this concurrent task?
- ...

Comment: However, when asking questions to the latter category users mostly thinks about it as `[threads]`, it is so disappointing that the tag-name isn't `[threads]` (it is a synonym) - as a developer it is in lesser cases I really think about "multi-threading".